# 'blog' prefix is hardcoded before permalinks wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

This happened without me changing anything except upgrading to 3.2.1 2 weeks ago.

in permalink settings, /blog is hardcoded before the text field for custom structure or category base. This screwed up all my posts across the site.
I did not install this under the 'blog' dir, nor does a 'blog' dir exist.
I'd prefer a solution without changing the core files.

[image: permalink settings screenshot]

I previous post with similar title does not answer this question, please to don't to that.

I'm using Multisite option turned on.
WP 3.2.1
I recently did a auto upgrade. I backed up the database but not the files >:(

Comment: Also went into network settings and edited the toplevel site (settings section), and changed the permalink setting there to no avail. If i go to the sub site, /blog/ is not prefixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Multisite version, this is by design that way. please see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Permalinks). but you may be lucky to remove it. I have recently also tested this, it works in some web server, but does not in others.

follow these steps:

1. go to the network(super) admin dashboard.
2. clikc 'All sites' on left side and select 'edit' the site from list.
3. you will see the main page has four tabs, click on 'settings'.
4. scroll down a bit, search for 'Permalink Structure' and remove '/blog'.
5. refresh your pages and see if it works.

Comment: I tried this before and my pages work but permalink settings admin page in on the specific site in question still says /blog/... So i didn't bother refreshing my pages...But it works...Thanks!

Comment: in that case, there is no easy solution for that.